# Where should sourceLocale be set in Angular.json?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

The [i18n Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-locale-id#set-the-source-locale-id) specify that you need to set the language id and locale extension by changing the `sourceLocale` field in your project's `Angular.json` file, but this field does not exist in a new project. Where should this field be defined in the json?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The string of the language id and locale extension in the form of `{language_id}-{locale_extension}` should be specified at `projects.{projectName}.i18n.sourceLocale` as seen below:

```
"projects": {
  "my-angular-project": {
    "i18n": {
      "sourceLocale": "en-US"
    }
  }
}
```

In this example we are using English US (`"en-US"`) as the Unicode Locale ID.